# Call methods from other controllers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

I'm trying to call a method from within another controller and getting a no method error.

So I have two controllers Jobs and Admin, I'm trying to call:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
```

I'm putting this command in the admin contoller's view, within the actual controller file for admin I have:

```
  # GET /jobs
  # GET /jobs.xml
  # GET /admin
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @jobs }
    end
```

Which I thought would pull everything I needed over yet I'm still getting a nomethoderror, so how should I include the jobs controller into the admin one?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: NoMethodError in Admin#jobs

Showing /Users/olliejudge/escrapid/app/views/admin/jobs.html.erb where line #19 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
Extracted source (around line #19):

16:     <th></th>
17:   </tr>
18: 
19: <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
20:   <tr>
21:     <td><%= job.job_title %></td>
22:     <td><%= job.Location %></td>

Answer (score 0):

from the code you posted, it appears that you are not using a query to get the jobs that you want from the database, eg

```
@jobs = Job.all
```

`Job.all` is an activerecord query that gets all the available records from the database. It sounds like you may be confused about how all the MVC pieces are intended to work together.

First, you should not be sharing methods across controllers, in reality your controllers will have very little code.

Rails will route a request, and look for an action defined in the controller, if it doesn't find one, it will go to the views folder and get the template of that action name there, eg a request to `Jobs#index` will look for an index action in the controller, and then if it isnt there, look for the `views/jobs/index.erb` template to render. So if you are serving static data and don't need to look up data, you dont even need an action in your controller. Often though, the action is needed because it is in the controller that you do your database and model lookups, and then pass those instance variables to the view. Keep all database queries and model actions out of the views.

```
def index
  @jobs = Job.all
end
```

and in the view

```
@jobs.each do |job| ...
```

The `respond_to` block is totally unnecessary unless you want to return a differently formatted template than html, like xml or json for a web service.

Comment: until the question was re-formated I didn't see that he was making a DB query in his example code. My answer is probably not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `jobs` action in Admin controller. You are loading @jobs in index action of Admin controller. If you want this work, rename `index` action of the `Admin` controller to jobs and add that route. One way you could add a route is by adding a line in `config/routes.rb`.

```
match '/jobs' => 'admin#jobs'
```

Read through [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: What I'm trying to do though is create an index of the jobs in the admin area, so therefore mapping /jobs to admin#jobs wouldn't really help. /jobs is already mapped to the jobs controller itself, as thats where I want to display the jobs to the end user. It's almost like the admin controller can't see anything from the jobs controller. Excuse my answers from being a tad idiotic, I'm still trying to get to grips with rails.